# Web Api Get FromUri - ArrayList Issue

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am new in web api and is now trying to converting the web service to web api. However i encountered issue while running the web api. Please help in this issue.

I have declared two ArrayList (ParameterName & ParameterValue) in the class for the model and it is optional to have value in both parameters.

```
public class PNAWcfData
{
    public PNAWcfData()
    {
        Server = "";
        Database = "";
        LoginID = "";
        Password = "";
        CmdTimeout = 30;
        Success = false;
    }
    public string Server { get; set; }
    public string Database { get; set; }
    //......
    public ArrayList ParameterName { get; set; }
    public ArrayList ParameterValue { get; set; }
    //......
```

When running it...
http://localhost:53386/api/webapi?Server=PNANTE813&Database=FF_ANDON&StoredProcName=udpDEV_GetProjectByPlant&ParameterName=Plant&ParameterValue=Plant1

If I did not put any value for the ParameterName & ParameterValue, then I am able to get the result.

If I put the value (Plant & Plant1) for the ParameterName & ParameterValue, then it is still success but somehow returned nothing. It is supposed to return the value.

controller code:

```
namespace PNAWebApi.Controllers
{
public class WebApiController : ApiController
{
    public PNAWcfData GetExecProcedureWithOutput([FromUri] PNAWcfData pPNAWcfData)
    {
        String lsConnStr;

        if (CheckConnData(pPNAWcfData.Server, pPNAWcfData.Database, pPNAWcfData.LoginID, pPNAWcfData.Password) == false)
        {
            pPNAWcfData.Success = false;
            pPNAWcfData.ErrMsg = "Database connection Info is not provided!";
        }
        else
        {
            lsConnStr = GetConnStr(pPNAWcfData.Server, pPNAWcfData.Database, pPNAWcfData.LoginID, pPNAWcfData.Password);

            try
            {
                if (pPNAWcfData.StoredProcName == "")
                {
                    pPNAWcfData.Success = false;
                    pPNAWcfData.ErrMsg = "Invalid Stored Procedure!";
                }
                else
                {
                    using (SqlConnection loConn = new SqlConnection(lsConnStr))
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand loCmd = new SqlCommand(pPNAWcfData.StoredProcName, loConn))
                        {
                            loCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            loCmd.CommandTimeout = pPNAWcfData.CmdTimeout;

                            if (pPNAWcfData.ParameterName != null && pPNAWcfData.ParameterValue != null)
                            {
                                for (int i = 0; i < pPNAWcfData.ParameterName.Count; ++i)
                                {
                                    loCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(pPNAWcfData.ParameterName[i].ToString(), pPNAWcfData.ParameterValue[i]);
                                }
                            }

                            if (loConn.State =.............
                                ....................
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                pPNAWcfData.Success = false;
                pPNAWcfData.ErrMsg = ex.Message;
            }
        }

        return pPNAWcfData;
    }
```

Comment: Please share the web api controller function

Comment: @MarcusH, added controller code.

Comment: You need to return something from the controller method for it to return something.. From the controller code you just added; It does not return anything.

Comment: @MarcusH, there is a return at the end of the end (have updated the code in this post), return the whole class. I did not include it earlier due to the code is a bit lengthy. 

p/s: ParameterName & ParameterValue are defined as ArrayList in class. The rest are primitive data type.

Comment: If you set the breakpoint inside the controller method. Does the ArrayLists get populated with the plant values? if not, then I would add string[] instead of ArrayList and try with that

Comment: when set the breakpoint, the ArrayLists is not populated with the plant values. 
i tried the normal Array, it is working! But the disadvantage of using it is i need to define the array size which I do not need to do the same if using ArrayLists.

Thanks @MarcusH! :)

Comment: Then use a List<string> instead, then you can add more values as you like. Should I add this as an answer?

Comment: @MarcusH, ok let me try to use List<string>. Yes, u can add this as an answer. Thank you very much for your advice! really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely there's a problem with the **parameter binding** in the GetExecProcedureWithOutput method where the class uses ArrayList which can't be populated with the FromUri attribute.

Instead of using the ArrayList I would try and use a "simpler" parameter type like `string[]` or `List<string>`.